# Email Attachment Download using C# , MFA enabled

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, multi-factor-authentication, openpop

OpenPop started failing from last week, after lot of debugging we found for the account which we are using,  MFA is enabled. we tried different ways to fix this but no luck, we requested to bypass MFA but as per organization polices we cant disable. Did any face similar issue? Is there a mechanism to download attachments where MFA is enabled for the email account receiving attachments.

Programming language which we are using is C#.

Exception received: Server did not accept user credentials
The server did not respond with a + response. The response was: "-ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

But when we are logging manually it works with same credentials but we have to authenticate MFA

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable the `POP3` protocol?

Comment: @KyleWang Yes,We did

Comment: @All, did any know how to solve this, we are banging our heads